# How to create a working custom order for product category page?

Tags: category, products

I have an issue with customising the order in which products appear on the main category listing page in Magento. I’m running CE version 1.8.1.0, and using the Grayscale custom theme, although this isn’t actually a theme issue.

Basically I wanted the products (of which there are 12) to appear in a very specific order. I tried both “Best value” (which turns out to be the same as Position) and created a new attribute called Listing Order, and in each case gave the products values from 1 to 12.

However, in the front end if I select to view all 12 (whether that’s “All” or “12” in the dropdown), the first 9 display ok (in 3 rows of 3) but then a column is missed, and the next product appears in the middle column, the one after that in the end column and the final product jumps down to a row by itself.

This happens both for sorting by Position and by the custom attribute, Listing Order.
It isn’t a problem with the CSS or template- if I sort by Price or by Name then I can view all 12 products on the page without any issue. But if I try using one of the other two ways of sorting, it jumps the first position in the fourth row (which would be the position for the 10th product) and messes up the page.

My client doesn’t want to sort it by Price or Name, but by their specific custom order.
So at the moment I’ve set the page to sort by Listing Order and only show 9 products, and the next 3 show on the 2nd page (and oddly enough they show fine). But again this isn’t a fix because the client wants them all on a single page.

I even tried a CSS workaround, adding a numeral or letter to the beginning of the product name and then sorting by name- using this technique to format and then hide the first letter:

h2.product-name::first-letter {font-size:1px; color:#fff !important;}

However although that hid the initial, all else that it did was cause even more product positions to be “jumped” meaning more products jumping down onto the next row.

This is the sort of thing that should really be straightforward, but as I’m constantly discovering to my cost, almost nothing in Magento is straightforward.
Has anyone got any ideas or come across this issue?

Comment: Has no one else come across this before?